# HTML/CSS - Triangle corners in table head (thead)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a table head with triangle corners. Exactly I would like to get this result:

[image]

I created something like that:

```
table .main_cat_left {
background-color: #57B3E3;
}

table .main_cat_center {
  border-left: 10px solid #57B3E3;
  border-top: 10px solid #FFC600;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

table .main_cat_right {
background-color: #FFC600;
}
```

But the result isn't good:

[image]

Is it possible to get this result wihtout using picture images and javascript (just with CSS) ??

Thanks.

EDIT;

Here is working example: https://jsfiddle.net/5o5qybk8/

Comment: Show your HTML, why you use table?

Comment: Because I would like to get this in table: http://s5.ifotos.pl/img/demopng_sqsnnqe.png

Comment: screen shot and bits of CSS aren't enough to help / point you in the right direction, we need a full example that reproduce your issue

Comment: OK, I edit my question, give me one minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may just use a gradient:

```
table .main_cat_center {
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom left, #FFC600 50%, #57B3E3 50%);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5o5qybk8/1/ or https://jsfiddle.net/5o5qybk8/3/

Answer (score 0):

Another approach;

```css
.yellowTriangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 100px 100px 0 0;
  border-color: #cc9433 #336699 transparent transparent;
}
.blueTriangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 100px 100px 0 0;
  border-color: #336699 #cc9433 transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="yellowTriangle">
      First
    </td>
    <td class="blueTriangle">
      Second
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1gs539nz/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible way of doing it, putting a skewed div on top of a regular div and coloring them differently. 
If you attach your original HTML people can help you fix your own code, I suppose it would be better for you.

```css
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 50%;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}

.nav-links {
  margin: 0 !important;
  display: block; 
  margin: auto;
}

.top {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: #FCC700;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  ;
}

.top-left {
  background: #272566;
  -ms-transform: skewX(30deg);/* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: skewX(30deg);/* Safari */
  transform: skewX(30deg);/* Standard syntax */
  left: -20px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.nav-links li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  margin: 3px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="top-left"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="bottom">
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li>Waluta</li>
      <li>Kupno</li>
      <li>Kupno</li>
      <li>Kupno (HURT)</li>
      <li>Sprezedaz (HURT)</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```